# How to prove that limit of floor function exists?

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The question is in the title.I have tried many many things,that did not get me anywhere really,so it would be pointless to write them here.

Note: [x] denotes floor of x

Basically I need to prove that if a is not an integer then $$\lim_{x \to a} [x] = [a]$$

Any takers?

Comment: What do you mean by "limit of floor function"? Limits are generally defined at points.

Comment: Do you have a particular limit in mind? It would help if you provide it, the question is too vague otherwise.

Comment: I will edit post in a second

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $a\in\mathbf{R}$ is not an integer, there is small enough $\epsilon$ so that there is no integer in $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$.

Solution (sketch): Suppose that $[a]=n\in\mathbf{Z}$. The above statement tells us when we are close enough to $a$, say within $\epsilon$ of $a$ for some $\epsilon>0$, that $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cap \mathbf{Z}=\emptyset$. So, for all $x$ close enough to $a$, that is, $x\in (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$, $[x]=n$ and therefore, $|[x]-[a]|=|n-n|=0$.

I'll leave it to you to formalize to your desire, but that's about it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am running out of paper to write on and it is late at night.Provide me a proof and save my restless soul if you get my drift... :D

Comment: @VanioBegic Go to sleep and write the proof in the morning.

Comment: What happens when epsilon is large and encompasses integers?